# Wrong style color visualized but just on real mobile devices

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have this very strange issue: the visualization of a menu opening/closing "icon" (char ☰) is correctly visualized in white color in desktop chrome view and in desktop inspecting/toggling as a mobile device. To the contrary, opening the same page with a real mobile device still using Chrome, the same "icon" is displayed in black color.

Here is the correct view on the desktop display (doesn't matter if it is in full screen or toggling to the mobile device the inspection tool):

[image]

Here is the wrong visualization on the mobile device display:

[image]

This is the HTML code:

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="closebtnn" style="color:#FFFFFF !important" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNavBar()">☰</a>
```

and here are the first lines of the style inspection tool:

[image]

Comment: It seems a cache problem on your mobile browser

Comment: How many mobile devices has this been tested on?  Which mobile operating systems?

Comment: no, cache erased several times and tested on 3 mobiles. Mine is a Samsung S8. You can try on yours at www.pharmacomparison.com, home page.

Comment: @fede72bari Well, I see it right on my smartphone

Comment: It works on an IPhone 6s, IOS 13, might be just android phones?

Comment: interesting, anyone with android experience a similar problem on a smartphone (not tablet)?

Comment: Could this be an issue with Dark Mode darkening the text character for you?

Comment: Or possibly accessibility high contrast settings?

Comment: no it is not. it seems to be mobile brand/model dependent